# Как сгенерировать текст кнопки HTML из JS файла?

Tags: javascript, html, button

У меня в HTML созданы 2 кнопки, у них есть свой `id` и `name`, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы они получали свой текст из `name` `button`, я думаю, что для этого я должен передать `id` и `name` `button` из HTML в JavaScript и из JS сгенерировать текст кнопки в HTML файл, но как это сделать не знаю. В любом случае буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: После загрузки древа DOM пройтись по всем кнопкам в цикле и в `innerHTML` записать значение атрибута `name`

Comment: Почему не заполнить текст там где заполняется name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После загрузки DOM дерева выполняете следующий код:

**Javascript:**

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].textContent = el[i].getAttribute('name');
}
```

```html
<button id="id1" name="test1"></button>
<button id="id2" name="test2"></button>
```

Comment: Спасибо брат, очень помогло.

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk, если данный ответ является ответом на Ваш вопрос, то отметье его галочкой слева от ответа. В будущем это может помочь людям при поиске аналогичного вопроса.

Comment: Ok, отметил, спасибо !

Answer (score 6):

В том случае, если вам не обязательно использовать JS, можно обойтись псевдоэлементом `:before` и в `content` вытащить нужный атрибут.

```css
button:before {
  content: attr(name);
}
```

```html
<button id="id1" name="test1"></button>
<button id="id2" name="test2"></button>
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что CSS скоро заменит JS, он уже много, где его заменяет. И самое главное, что это мне даже нравится.))

Comment: @SonicMyst данный прием совсем не новый. Но, да, сейчас при помощи css  можно очень много всего реализовать без использования JS.

Comment: Спасибо брат за помощь, проста требовали сделать это с помощью js

Comment: Не вопрос. Я потому и написал, что это альтернатива JS в данном примере)